# Rails: Rendering partial in div on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I'm building a webapp that features a UI split into two sides, a menu bar and a content area.
The menu bar has a listing of the titles of all blogs that a user has written.  When a title is clicked, the content area should change to show the posts of that blog.

1.) So on my menu bar, I have:

```
<%= link_to blog.title, blog, :remote=>true %>
```

And in my content area, I have:

```
<div id="contenthere"></div>
```

2.) So by my understanding, this should trigger the show method of the blog controller. There, I have the following in the method:

```
@blog = Blog.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
   format.js { render :show_blog }
end
```

3.) Which should go look for a file called show_blog.js.erb in views/blogs folder:

```
$("#contenthere").html("<%=escape_javascript(render :partial=>"show_blog")%>");
```

Which will take my div with commenthere id and render the _show_blog.html.erb partial (located in the blog view folder) with the blog parameter equal to the @blog parameter that was set in my blog controller.

4.) So my show blog partial has this code:

```
<%=@blog.title %>
<%=@blog.user_id %>
```

EDIT:  Actually, I search around and found out that I can't use the method 'render' from within the assets folder-- where do I put the js.erb then?  I've moved it to the blog view folder, home view folder (index.html.erb), and just the /view/ folder...  The error is gone, but the link is not working...

EDIT: Put the show_blog.js.erb in my views/blogs folder, since it's the blog controller calling it.  Nothing happening when I click the link and no JS errors shown in console.  Is the js being called at all?

EDIT: Changed to reflect my final answer.

Comment: Have you tried: `$("#contenthere").html("<%= render('show_blog', :blog=>@blog) %>");` remove the `j(...)`

Comment: you should use `escape_javascript(render..)` rather than `j(render...)`

It would also be valuable to know whether the error is from rendering the partial or from the controller. Try `render 'show_blog'` (if it's in a directory with the same name as the controller) rather than using a symbol

Comment: Actually, I found out it was because render can't be called from assets folder... Which folder do I move the show_blog.js.erb file to?

Comment: it goes in views/nameofcontroller, or views/anything, but in the second case you have to use render 'anything/show_blog'

Comment: Check if you have any JS errors.

Comment: No JS errors showing on console.  Does not seem to even be loading the js file when I click on the link?

Comment: What do rails log show? Are rails receiving request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution in the end--- The partial was calling for blog.title, blog.user_id, but @blog was the actual param that was passed.  Just had to change to @blog.title and @blog.user_id.

Answer (score 1):

```
@blog = Blog.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
   format.js { render :show_blog }
end
```

That is not Rails default logic.

You didn't provided, how method is called, suppose

```
   def show_blog
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
       format.js 
    end
    end
```

Then, Rails will look for `show_blog.js.erb` in `views/blogs` and render that file.

Also, you need to pass actual instance to partial, because patrial is stand-alone chunk of code and doesn't know, what @blog is:

```
$("#contenthere").append("<%=j render :partial=>"show_blog", :locals=>{:@blog=>@blog}%>");
```

Comment: Hm, well, actually in the end, just writing render :show_blog works fine, because it looks for a js file titled show_blog.  I don't need to define a new method called show_blog.  Also, the partial was able to pick up on the instance of the @ blog from the @ blog in the blog controller, which got it from the id parameter in the first link.  The final solution in the question after editing should work fine and is a little less bulky.

Comment: @ays0110, method was just to show Rails logic, and I provided name to show what file will Rails look and where, and actually, you just edited your question absolutely following my answer. (not mentioning, that question should be question and answer should be answer, and messing eah over prevents this whole tread to be helpful to other users)